# fill listview2 based on checked item in listview1 from database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to populate listview2 based on checked items of listview1

I have tried the code but its filling listview2 item when I uncheck the item from listview1

```vb
Private Function selectionfromDeptTofillLv2() As Boolean 
    Dim i As Integer, Yn As Boolean
    Yn = False
    Dim strDept As String = ""
    For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        ListView1.Items(i).Selected = True
        If ListView1.Items(i).Checked = True Then
            If Trim(strDept) <> "" Then strDept = strDept & ","
            strDept = strDept & Trim(ListView1.Items(i).Tag)
            Yn = True
        End If
    Next
    
    If Yn = True Then
        Dim strSQL As String = "", strSQLdept As String = ""

        conn = GetConnect()
        conn.Open()

        strSQL = "select SubName,SubDeptID from DepartmentSub where active=1"
        If Trim(strDept) <> "" Then strSQLdept = strSQLdept & " And DepartmentID In (" & strDept & ")" & " order by SubName"

        strSQL = strSQL & strSQLdept
        'MsgBox(strSQL)
        Dim cmd3 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
        Dim sda3 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd3)
        Dim dt3 As DataTable = New DataTable()

        sda3.Fill(dt3)

        With ListView2
            ListView3.Clear()
            .Clear()
            .View = View.Details
            .GridLines = True
            .Columns.Clear()
            .Items.Clear()
            .Columns.Add(" ", 30)
            .Columns.Add("Sub Department Name", 250, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

            For Each row As DataRow In dt3.Rows
                'Add Item to ListView.
                Dim item As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
                item.SubItems.Add(row("SubName").ToString())
                item.Tag = Val(row("SubDeptID").ToString)
                item.Checked = False
                .Items.Add(item)
                item = Nothing
            Next
        End With
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Function

'selectall in listview1
Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.Click
    For Each lvitem As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.Items
        lvitem.Checked = CheckBox2.Checked
    Next
    selectionfromDeptTofillLv2()
End Sub

'calling sub from listview1 below
Private Sub ListView1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseUp
    selectionfromDeptTofillLv2()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with VBScript?

Comment: Put a breakpoint near the top of your Function and step through your code line by line. Check the value of the variables by holding your cursor over them. You will be able to see where you are not getting expected results. BTW, your function isn't returning anything.

Comment: Pls Reply, Need Help